# Display react-intl value in test snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-intl

I globally mocked react intl (`formatMessage: message => message.defaultMessage,`) and when I use intl.formatMessage inside a React component with some value it is not displayed within test snapshot.

```
intl.formatMessage(messages.xxx, { token: <b>something</b> });
```

part of messages.js:

```
xxx: {
  defaultMessage: 'Something something {token}',
  id: `ComponentX.xxx`,
},
```

When I want to render a snapshot but inside snapshot there is:

```
Something something {token}
```

Whould could I do to have in snapshot the code below?

```
Something something <b>something</b>
```